# Mongoose join additional collection to two aggregated collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is a new requirement I need to implement in my personal project. I successfully joined two collections using aggregate ([previous question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278693/mongoose-join-two-collections-and-get-only-specific-fields-from-the-joined-colle). Now, I have a new collection that I need to join. Please see codes below:

Student model:

```
{
  fullname: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
}
```

Exams model:

```
{
  test: { type: String, required: false },
  top10: [
    type: {
      studentId: { type: String, required: true },
      score: { type: Number, required: false },
    }
  ]
}
```

Aggregated collections:

```
db.exams.aggregate([
{ $unwind: "$top10" },
{
$lookup: {
  from: "students",
  localField: "top10.studentId",
  foreignField: "_id",
  as: "students"
}
},
{ $addFields: { students: { $arrayElemAt: ["$students", 0] } } },
{
$group: {
  _id: "$_id",
  test: { $first: "$test" },
  students: {
    $push: {
      studentId: "$top10.studentId",
      score: "$top10.score",
      fullname: "$students.fullname"
    }
  }
}
}
])
```

Now, the 3rd collection is called **Teacher**.

Teacher model:

```
{
  fullName: { type: String, required: false },
  studentId: { type: String, required: false }
}
```

Expected output should be:

```
{
 "test": "Sample Test #1",
 "students": [
        {
            "studentId": "5f22ef443f17d8235332bbbe",
            "fullname": "John Smith",
            "score": 11,
            "teacher": "Dr. Hofstadter"
            
        },
        {
            "studentId": "5f281ad0838c6885856b6c01",
            "fullname": "Erlanie Jones",
            "score": 9,
            "teacher": "Mr. Roberts"
        },
        {
            "studentId": "5f64add93dc79c0d534a51d0",
            "fullname": "Krishna Kumar",
            "score": 5,
            "teacher": "Ms. Jamestown"
        }
    ]
}
```

Appreciate kind of help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add these 2 more pipelines before the $group pipeline,

- `$lookup` join collection with teacher
- `$addFields` to get convert array to object
- `$group` to add teacher name in students array

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "teacher",
      localField: "top10.studentId",
      foreignField: "studentId",
      as: "students.teacher"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "students.teacher": { $arrayElemAt: ["$students.teacher", 0] }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      test: { $first: "$test" },
      students: {
        $push: {
          studentId: "$top10.studentId",
          score: "$top10.score",
          fullname: "$students.fullname",
          teacher: { $ifNull: ["$students.teacher.fullname", ""] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CUaAdHBA8pK)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I learnt from you. Another question. How do we handle if no teacher exists for the student? I want to display empty string for that.

Comment: I have updated with $ifNull operator because when its not fount that will return null.

Comment: thanks @turivishal. Btw, is it possible to display the result set in object rather than array?

Comment: add two new pipelines at the end $unwind students and $replaceWith students [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oHVEJ-9TGvS)

Comment: Sorry I meant, if I need to only display single record, since aggregate displays result in array, is there a way to display the result in an object? similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375301/is-it-possible-to-get-single-result-in-aggregate

Comment: No its not possible to get an only a object in aggregate(), you can clearly see all the answers on that question. you can just limit $limit: 1, but this will return an array with single object.

Comment: Okay, so what can you suggest an alternative to that?

Comment: You need to do it after query to access object from zero position. like `let response = await aggregate(); console.log(response[0])`

Comment: Okay thanks! That's what I also thought of. Btw, is there a way we can search a record in the third collection? For example, search fullName === 'Erlanie Jones'.

Comment: You can do it same as your previous question, lookup and then match