# Mongoose join two collections and get referenced data in two properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm doing a simple follow friend functionality.

Please see my codes below:

**Following schema:**

```
{
 "userId": { type: String },
 "followers": [{ "followerId": type: String }],
 "followings": [{ "followingId": type: String }], 
}
```

**User schema:**

```
{
 "fullName": { type: String } 
}
```

**Note:** user 8 has 1 follower and 2 followings.

Now, my expected output should be like this:

```
        "userId": 8,
        "followers": [
            {
                "followerId": 4,
                "fullName": "Rose Marriott",
            },
            {
                "followerId": 5,
                "fullName": "James Naismith",
            }
        ],
        "followings": [
            {
                "followingId": 1,
                "fullName": "Russell Oakham",
            },
            {
                "followingId": 5,
                "fullName": "James Naismith",
            }
        ]
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
 db.followings.aggregate([
 { $unwind: "$followers" },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "followers.followerId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "users"
        }
    },
    { 
        $addFields: 
        { 
            users: { $arrayElemAt: ["$users", 0] },
        },
    },
    { $unwind: "$followings" },
    {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "followings.followingId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "users2"
        }
    },
    { 
        $addFields: 
        { 
            users2: { $arrayElemAt: ["$users2", 0] },
        },
    },
    { $match: {"userId": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            userId: { $first: "$userId" },
            followers: {
                $push: {
                    followerId: "$followers.followerId",
                    fullName: "$users.fullName",
                }
            },
            followings: {
                $push: {
                    followingId: "$followings.followingId",
                    fullName: "$users2.fullName",
                }
            }
        }
      }
  ]);
```

But I'm getting 2 followers and 2 followings. I wonder what's causing this issue. Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try,

- `$addFields` to make a unique array called `userIds` form both arrays `followers` and `followings`, `$setUnion` to get unique ids,
- `$lookup` with users collection
- `$project` to show fields,

  - `followers` get fullName, $map to iterate loop of `followers` and get the name of `followerId` from users array using `$reduce` and `$cond`
  - `followings` get fullName, $map to iterate loop of `followings` and get the name of `followingId` from users array using `$reduce` and `$cond`

```
db.followings.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      userIds: {
        $setUnion: [
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$followers",
              in: "$$this.followerId"
            }
          },
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$followings",
              in: "$$this.followingId"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "userIds",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "users"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      userId: 1,
      followers: {
        $map: {
          input: "$followers",
          as: "f",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$f",
              {
                fullName: {
                  $reduce: {
                    input: "$users",
                    initialValue: "",
                    in: {
                      $cond: [
                        { $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$f.followerId"] },
                        "$$this.fullName",
                        "$$value"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      followings: {
        $map: {
          input: "$followings",
          as: "f",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$f",
              {
                fullName: {
                  $reduce: {
                    input: "$users",
                    initialValue: "",
                    in: {
                      $cond: [
                        { $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$f.followingId"] },
                        "$$this.fullName",
                        "$$value"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AoKGZ_21MuS)

Comment: Hi thanks for this! I have another question. How do we add two additional collections such as images and likes and display user image and likes along in the followings and followers arrays?

Answer (score 0):

when working with relations on Mongoose you should create the relationship based on a unique id, and then reference the document. In your case, it would be:

```
followingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    {
     "followers": [{type: mongoose.Schema.types.ObjectId, ref="User"}],
     "followings": [{type: mongoose.Schema.types.ObjectId, ref="User"}], 
    }
})

userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullname: String,
})
```

be aware that the userId will be created automatically by Mongoose with a field called _id. so, the end result of creating a new following documents would be:

```
{
    _id: "klajdsfñalkdjf" //random characters created by mongoose,
    followers: ["adfadf134234", "adfadte345"] //same as before, these are Ids of the users randomly generated by mongoose
    followers: ["adfadf134234", "adfadte345"] 
}

{
 _id: adfadf134234,
 fullName: "alex",
}
```

now, because there is no use for us to have a random number as information in the fields of following and followers in the following object, we can now use the method .populate() that can be used over the document itself to transform those Ids into actual information. You can see more about it here: [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-populate)

our final result would be something like this:

```
{
    _id: "añfakdlsfja",
    followers : [{_id: "adlfadsfj", fullName: "alex"}],
    following : [{_id: "adfadfad" , fullName: "other"}, {_id: "dagadga", fullName: "another"}]
}
```